# Unable to minus the values of variable in oracle form

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I want to minus my data value that are in the variables, but my code is not working.

My code is below

```
DECLARE

  REEL_W NUMBER;

BEGIN

   SELECT WEIGHT 
   INTO REEL_W FROM REELS_TABLE
   WHERE R_ID = :R_ID_1_PLAIN;

   REEL_W := REEL_W - :R_ID_1_W_CON;

END;
```

*here is my oracle forms picture:*

[image]

Comment: What's the error saying?

Comment: It is difficult to debug a "not working" error message.

Comment: there is no error and no any effect.

Comment: Why would you need a PL/SQL block for that? SELECT WEIGHT - :R_ID_1_W_CON FROM REELS_TABLE WHERE R_ID = :R_ID_1_PLAIN; No?

Comment: What do you expect from that block? It does not output anything, so "no any effect" is to be expected

Comment: sir i attached my form picture that may defines my requirements

Comment: This seems to be a variant of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53833939/146325). You didn't get an answer to that because it was not clear. Alas this question seems no clearer. Please provide a better description of what you are trying to achieve. I appreciate posting a reproducible test case is difficult with Forms because so much functionality is built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Firstly, I assume the field `:R_ID_1_W_CON` is numeric, isn't it? Your problem might be related with null values, so had better using `nvl()` function. By the way, exceptions might be raised due to `select` statements with `into` clause, so we need to handle them.
So, consider using the below one :*

```
DECLARE
  REEL_W NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT nvl(WEIGHT,0)-nvl(:R_ID_1_W_CON,0)
    INTO REEL_W
    FROM REELS_TABLE
   WHERE R_ID = :R_ID_1_PLAIN;
 EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN REEL_W := 0;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your picture you are writing a `ON-INSERT` trigger.
In `ON-INSERT` you should add an insert statement.

I assume that is the reason why it is not working.

You should use a `PRE-INSERT` trigger or a `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger to do this kind of work.